# Discord-Minecraft integration

Tags: minecraft-java-edition-server, discord

I have heard YouTubers link a chat room in Discord with their Minecraft chat. Is there any way to do so ourselves as well? My friend has a Minecraft server and I want to help him with linking it to his Discord server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick google search showed this result. A spigot plugin called [DiscordSRV](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/discordsrv.18494/), compatible with versions from 1.7 to 1.16. From the plugin's page:

> ### Intended usage
>
> Using this plugin, you are able to give players the
> ability to chat in-game to chat with players on your Discord server as
> well as having people on the Discord server be able to chat with
> people on the server- this is useful for the situation of someone not
> being at their computer and being able to talk in-game.